# Rails update to version 2.3.8, error :undefined method `html_safe!' with simple_form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've just updated my Rails gem version from 2.3.5 to 2.3.8
I'm using simple_form v=1.0

When I try to render a form I have an error message :
undefined method `html_safe!' for #

Can I patch it in my app or maybe it must be fixed in the simple_form version 1.0 ?

Thanks for your advices :-)

Fro_oo

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just need to update your simple_form plugin.  it is fixed with this commit:

http://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/commit/1f288c0b7ca213d2402ef9e62dbefe82dcaa8b7c

just make sure you install v 1.0, that is rails 2.3 support.